# Need help in avoiding 'Wrong Answer' on SPOJ

Tags: c++, algorithm

Problem : http://www.spoj.com/problems/EGYPIZZA/

I've been trying to solve this 'PIZZA' problem for quite some time and I have tried many, many
inputs and it seems to be working fine on my machine but the online judge keeps refusing to accept mu code saying its the wrong answer!!
Please help me out...
Here's my code:

```
 #include<iostream>
#include<cstring>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    char str[4],b[3][4]= {"1/4","1/2","3/4"};
    unsigned int n, s = 1, count1 = 0, count2 = 0, count3 = 0;
    scanf("%u",&n);
    while(n--)
    {
        cin>>str;
        if(strcmp(str,b[0])==0)
            count2++;               
         else if(strcmp(str,b[1])==0)
             count1++;
         else if(strcmp(str,b[2])==0)
              count3++;
    }
    while(count3!=0 && count2!=0)
      {
               count2--; count3--; s++;
      }  
        if(count1%2!=0)
          if(count2/2!=0)
            {
                    count2-=2; count1--; s++;
            }   
            s = s + (count1/2) + (count1%2) + (count2/4) + (count2%4) + count3 ;
    printf("%u\n",s);
    return 0;
}
```

EDIT :
I have updated my code after your suggestions please check it out guys!!
Still giving wrong answer..

Comment: I am not familiar with SPOJ, but if I read it, it feels like they expect a file with a specific format as an input.

Comment: can you explain why the 1st sample output is 4. because 3/4+3/4+1/2=2 + 1 for our friend = 3

Comment: its because everyone wants their share in one slice. Meaning you can't buy two pizzas cut out 3/4 for two of them and use the other two 1/4 to form a 1/2. In this case we order 3 pizzas each for the three of them and one extra for the host.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Accepted Solution:

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string s;
    int n, sum = 1, count1 = 0, count2 = 0, count3 = 0, extra;
    cin >> n;
    for (int i=0; i < n; i++)
    {
        cin >> s;
        if (s == "1/2")count1 ++;
        if (s == "1/4")count2 ++;
        if (s == "3/4")count3 ++;
    }

    sum += count3 + count1/2.0 + 0.5;
    extra = count3 + (count1%2)*2;
    if (count2 >= extra)
    {
       count2 -= extra;
       sum += count2 / 4.0 + 0.75;
    }

    cout << sum << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

This problem would be more interesting if aboTrika don't insist on having his pizza one piece as the others. :)

Comment: Can you explain the algorithm??(the lines after the for loop)

Comment: I must say this solution is the most elegant I have ever come accross.
Did you come up with it yourself?

Comment: Yes. I participated in the ACM/ICPC 3 times as a contestant, twice as a coach and once as a judge for the arab region :). Please, vote as correct answer for me.

Answer (score 1):

Your program has numerous problems, such as using vectors where simple counters will suffice, and using floating point where integer arithmetic is appropriate.  Perhaps the most serious problem is the statement `s = s + q/4 + h/2` which in effect satisfies most requests for 1/4 pizza by grouping quarter-pizzas together and grouping half-pizzas together.  Instead, requests for 1/4 pizza should be used first to complement as many 3/4-pizza requests as possible, then to fill up a 1/2-pizza request if the requested number of halves is odd, and only then used together.